# Data Binding in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: asp.net, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I want all the records created in ASP.NET Web Application to be shown in my Mobile App Xamarin.Forms. What's happening to my program is that I was able to create records in my Web Application but I wasn't able to make it bind it in my Xamarin.Forms Mobile app. I have created a MainViewModel that will get the records from the Web Application which I have binded in my MainPage.
What can I do to show all the records I have created? 
These are my codes. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you so much.

MainPageMain.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinDemoApp"
         x:Class="XamarinDemoApp.MainPageMain"
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:XamarinDemoApp.ViewModels;assembly=XamarinDemoApp"
         BackgroundColor="Teal"
         Title=" Title Bar">



 <ContentPage.BindingContext>
  <ViewModels:MainViewModel/>
   </ContentPage.BindingContext>


  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeesList}"
          HasUnevenRows="True">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                  FontSize="24"/>
          <Label Text="{Binding Department}"
                  FontSize="24"/>

        </StackLayout>

      </ViewCell>

     </DataTemplate>

     </ListView.ItemTemplate>



  </ListView>

   <Label Text="This is the Main Page"/>

   </StackLayout>
 </ContentPage>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using XamarinDemoApp.Models;
using XamarinDemoApp.Services;

namespace XamarinDemoApp.ViewModels
    {
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{    


    private List<Employee> _employeesList;

    public List<Employee> EmployeesList
    {
        get {return _employeesList;}
        set 
        {
            _employeesList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }



    public MainViewModel()
    {

        InitializeDataAsync();
    }

    private async Task InitializeDataAsync()
    {
        var employeesServices = new EmployeesServices();

        EmployeesList = await employeesServices.GetEmployeesAsync();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
           PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are using `List<Employee>` as a source to your listview.

Refer this [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding/). It says :

> If you want the ListView to automatically update as items are added, removed and changed in the underlying list, you'll need to use an ObservableCollection. ObservableCollection is defined in System.Collections.ObjectModel and is just like List, except that it can notify ListView of any changes

Update your code to use ObservableCollection.

```
ObservableCollection<Employee> employees= new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

// Convert/Add your list in observable collection
foreach (Employee e in EmployeesList )
{ 
    employees.Add(new Employee { Name=e.Name,Department=e.Department } )
}
```

After that you can set this as a source to your ListView.

**UPDATE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using XamarinDemoApp.Models;
using XamarinDemoApp.Services;

namespace XamarinDemoApp.ViewModels
    {
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{    


    private ObservableCollection<Employee> _employeesList;

    public ObservableCollection<Employee> EmployeesList
    {
        get {return _employeesList;}
        set 
        {
            _employeesList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }



    public MainViewModel()
    {

        InitializeDataAsync();
    }

    private async Task InitializeDataAsync()
    {
        var employeesServices = new EmployeesServices();

        var EmployeesListNew = await employeesServices.GetEmployeesAsync();

        foreach (Employee e in EmployeesListNew )
        { 
            EmployeesList.Add(new Employee { Name=e.Name,Department=e.Department } )
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
           PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I put that codes Sir? What part of my file? I'm so sorry i'm just a newbie here. Should it look like this? http://pastie.org/10854692

Comment: You can do this in your `InitializeDataAsync` method. Change your datatype of _employeesList to `ObservableCollection<Employee>`

Comment: The datatype of _employeesList is not in located in the 'InitializeDataAsync' method. I'm having a hardtime understanding it i'm sorry Sir. Can you please edit my code and paste it here http://pastie.org/. Click the 'CREATE PASTE' button and copy it's URL.' Then will you please send me the link? Thanks a lot Sir.

Comment: It's not working Sir.  The label I created is the only thing that appear . '<Label Text="This is the Main Page"/>'

Comment: Did you debug your code? Check if the EmployeeList is getting populated.@JayceeEvangelista

Comment: How will I do that Sir? The EmployeeList receives a value because I was able to display data on the Web Application but not on the mobile.

Comment: I am saying does the data come in your response? `var EmployeesListNew = await employeesServices.GetEmployeesAsync();` does the EmployessListNew get populated with your data?@JayceeEvangelista

Comment: How will I know if the EmployeesListNew gets populated or not? Sorry Sir.

Comment: Learn how to debug your code in visual studio. Put a breakpoint where you want to see the program execution or some values in debug mode.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx